# Proof that the sequence $n - n²\sin\frac{1}{n}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Have been trying to proof that the sequence is not Cauchy, but I didn't get anywhere. It seems the sequence is convergent, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: remember the Maclaurin series for the sine.

Comment: This is bounded and eventually monotone.

Comment: Can you use $\sin x=x+O(x^3)$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I can't.

Comment: @KennyLau Thanks, will try to prove it is bounded and monotone.

Comment: @KennyLau Is it possible to prove it is decreasing using only $\sin x \le x$?

Comment: @mechanodroid $\sin\dfrac1n \ge \dfrac1n$

Comment: @KennyLau It's the other way around.

Comment: @mechanodroid sorry :P

Comment: @KennyLau "This is bounded and eventually monotone" Is this significantly easier to prove than the statement itself? If not, how is your comment helping?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:)**

Let $n=\dfrac1y$ and compute $\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{y-\sin y}{y^2}$.

Comment: Thanks, got it now.

Answer (score 1):

This approach will be useful to you in the future:

First note that and approximation of third order gives $\sin(1/n)=1/n+O(1/n^3)$. Then
$$n-n^2\sin(1/n)=n-n-n^2O(1/n^3)=O(1/n)\to0$$